# how to add a right click menu to each cell of QTableView in PyQt

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, contextmenu, qtableview, qtablewidgetitem

I want to add a right click menu to delete, rename or open image in each of cell of QTAbleView in the rigt click menu, I have tried and found everyone is trying to add menu to a header in tableview, i tried below but that seems not working in the code below..

```
class GalleryUi(QtGui.QTableView):
    """ Class contains the methods that forms the
        UI of Image galery
    """
    def __init__(self, imagesPathLst=None, parent=None):
        super(GalleryUi, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__sw = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).width()
        self.__sh = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(self).height()
        self.__animRate = 1200
        self._imagesPathLst = imagesPathLst
        self._thumb_width = 200
        self._thumb_height = self._thumb_width + 20
        self.setUpWindow(initiate=True)

        self._startControlBar()

        self._connections()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):

        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        renameAction = QtGui.QAction('Exit', self)
        renameAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.menu.addAction(renameAction)
        self.menu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos())

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        # in case gallery is launched by Slideshow this is not needed
        if hasattr(self, 'bar'):
            self.bar.close()

    def _startControlBar(self):
        if not self._slideShowWin:
            self.bar = controlBar.ControlBar()
            self.bar.show()
            self.bar.exitBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
            self.bar.openBtn.clicked.connect(self.selectSetNewPath)


    def _connections(self):
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL(self.customContextMenuRequested(QtCore.QPoint)), self, QtCore.SLOT(displayMenu(QtCore.QPoint)))

    def displayMenu(self, pos):
        self.menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        self.menu.addAction(self.close)
        self.menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

    def selectSetNewPath(self):

        path = utils._browseDir("Select the directory that contains images")
        self._imagesPathLst = utils.ingestData(path)
        # sets model when new folder is choosen
        self.updateModel()

    def setUpWindow(self, initiate=False):
        """ Method to setup window frameless and fullscreen,
            setting up thumbnaul size and animation rate
        """

        if not self._imagesPathLst:
            self.selectSetNewPath()
        # sets model once at startup when window is being drawn!
        if initiate:
            self.updateModel()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.__sw, self.__sh)
        self.setColumnWidth(self._thumb_width, self._thumb_height)
        self.setShowGrid(False)
        self.setWordWrap(True)
        self.show()

        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.selChanged)

    def updateModel(self):
        col = self.__sw/self._thumb_width 
        self._twoDLst = utils.convertToTwoDList(self._imagesPathLst, col)
        lm = MyListModel(self._twoDLst, col,
            (self._thumb_width, self._thumb_height), self)
        self.setModel(lm)



    def keyPressEvent(self, keyevent):
        """ Capture key to exit, next image, previous image,
            on Escape , Key Right and key left respectively.
        """
        event = keyevent.key()
        if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self._exitGallery()



def main(imgLst=None):
    """ method to start gallery standalone
    """
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window =  GalleryUi(imgLst)
    window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_path = os.getcwd()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        current_path = sys.argv[1:]
    main(utils.ingestData(current_path))
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`QTableView` has `contextMenuEvent()` event, to show a right-click menu:

- Create a `QMenu` inside this event
- Add some `QAction`s to `QMenu`
- connect each `QAction` to slots using `triggered` signal of `QAction`
- call `popup(QCursor.pos())` on `QMenu`

When user right-click the tableView the cell under the mouse pointer will be selected and at the same time a menu will appear. When user selects an action on the menu, the connected slot will be called, get the selected cell of tabel in this slot and perform the required action on this cell.

```
...
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
    self.menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
    renameAction = QtGui.QAction('Rename', self)
    renameAction.triggered.connect(lambda: self.renameSlot(event))
    self.menu.addAction(renameAction)
    # add other required actions
    self.menu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
    ...

def renameSlot(self, event):
    print "renaming slot called"
    # get the selected row and column
    row = self.tableWidget.rowAt(event.pos().y())
    col = self.tableWidget.columnAt(event.pos().x())
    # get the selected cell
    cell = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
    # get the text inside selected cell (if any)
    cellText = cell.text()
    # get the widget inside selected cell (if any)
    widget = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, col)
...
```

Comment: I have added the contextMenuEvent but it still doesn't seem to work !!

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" means what? What happened when you right-click the tableView?

Comment: in your edited code, you saved the reference to `QMenu` object in `menu` where as at the time of `popup()` and `addAction()` you called these methods on self.menu!

Comment: I still don't see how you can access the cell in this manner, care to update the example?

Comment: @user1766555, I updated the answer, both methods are updated.

Comment: I ended up doing it in a different manner, where should I paste my example? Through a link?

Comment: Yes, if it's already on a web page, you can paste a link in a comment below, otherwise you can add another answer at the bottom of this thread.

Answer (score 10):

I finally implemented it this way!!

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, pos):
    if self.selectionModel().selection().indexes():
        for i in self.selectionModel().selection().indexes():
            row, column = i.row(), i.column()
        menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        openAction = menu.addAction("Open")
        deleAction = menu.addAction("Delete")
        renaAction = menu.addAction("Rename")
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(pos))
        if action ==openAction:
            self.openAction(row, column)

def openAction(self, row, column):
    if self._slideShowWin:
        self._slideShowWin.showImageByPath(self._twoDLst[row][column])
        self._animateUpOpen()

def deleteSelected(self):
    # TODO
    pass
```

that works like a charm !!!