# PyQt - Add right click to a widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt and I want to add a right click to a widget, but I can't find any code on this subject online.

How can you do it ?

Comment: Related: (if you want to spawn a context menu) [python 2.7 - how to add a right click menu to each cell of QTableView in PyQt - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930764/how-to-add-a-right-click-menu-to-each-cell-of-qtableview-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to override the methods that take care of it.

In this case you will override the mousePressEvent, have a look on this and see if it makes sense and works for what you need.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Left Button Clicked")
        elif QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            #do what you want here
            print("Right Button Clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWidget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another good way to do that would be installing a event filter in your object and overriding its eventFilter. Inside that method you would make what you want. Remember you can always make use of pyqtSignal for good practices and call another object to make the job, not overloading the method with a lot of logic.

Here is another small example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, QObject, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
                print("Right button clicked")
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWidget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** Remember that this last example will receive ALL KIND OF EVENTS, so you will have to be careful and make sure it's the one you want and not runtime breaking your app calling methods of your event that doesn't exist because it's not of that kind. For example if you call `event.button()` without making sure before that it is a `QEvent.MouseButtonPress` your app would break of course.

There are other ways to do that, these are the most known ones.

Answer (score -2):

I have come up with a pretty simple way of doing this and works perfectly. In the ControlMainWindow class add the following to initialise the Context menu policy as CustomeContextMenu where listWidget_extractedmeters will be the name of your QListWidget:

```
    self.listWidget_extractedmeters.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.listWidget_extractedmeters.connect(self.listWidget_extractedmeters,QtCore.SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.listItemRightClicked)
```

Then in the ControlMainwindow class the following functions allow you to add context menu items and to call a funtion that performs some functionality:

```
def listItemRightClicked(self, QPos): 
    self.listMenu= QtGui.QMenu()
    menu_item = self.listMenu.addAction("Remove Item")
    self.connect(menu_item, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.menuItemClicked) 
    parentPosition = self.listWidget_extractedmeters.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))        
    self.listMenu.move(parentPosition + QPos)
    self.listMenu.show() 

def menuItemClicked(self):
    currentItemName=str(self.listWidget_extractedmeters.currentItem().text() )
    print(currentItemName)
```

Comment: How to do it in  PyQT5?