# Qt Context Menu for each item in ListView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I use PyQt5 + Qt Designer 5. Is it possible to show Context Menu when I rightclick on item in ListView area?

The best I've got to is context menu opening when I click anywhere inside of ListView area but not the one item.

Comment: Take a look at [Cell menu qtableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930764/how-to-add-a-right-click-menu-to-each-cell-of-qtableview-in-pyqt) and [context menu for items in a qlistwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890473/how-do-i-make-a-context-menu-for-each-item-in-a-qlistwidget).